# SourceTree won't show branch list

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

[image]

After installing SourceTree on Windows 10, and doing all (?) the necessary configuration, I can see my branch graph, **but the branch list is not showing**. The processing icon shows indefinitely.

I can do a successful pull, so I know it's hitting the server, and I know my credentials are successfully configured.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times. But I think the final solution came when I...

1. Did a full uninstall
2. Used [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to find and remove all residual settings and preferences files (of which there were many).
3. Reinstalled.

Now it works. Hope this helps the next guy.